# How can i close the alert dialog in kotlin Programmatically?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have alert dialog and I want to close the box programmatically in some action `alert.dismiss();` not working --> unresolved reference

```
val alert: AlertDialog.Builder = AlertDialog.Builder(view.context)
alert.setTitle(this.notes[position])
alert.setMessage("choose what you want to do")

var viewOption = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.item_option, container, false)

alert.setView(viewOption)

val btn = viewOption.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnId)
btn.setOnClickListener {
    // i want to close the box her after some action
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
val dialog = alert.show()
```

Then, inside your listener:

```
dialog.dismiss()
```

Comment: Many thanks,  worked